# WebStorm/PhpStorm double quotes in TypeScript auto import

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using TypeScript style with single quotes, double quotes are used exclusively in HTML templates.

WebStorm/PhpStorm auto import adds `import` statements with double quotes and ruins the style. I guess this applies to all JetBrains products.

How can this behaviour be fixed?

Comment: Like any other language in any JetBrains tool, alter the code style settings in your preferences.

Comment: That's true, just found it, where the answer suggests. There was nothing useful on 'quote' search in preferences.

Answer (score 944, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the following option:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | TypeScript`
3. `"Punctuation" tab | Generated code -> Quote marks`

---

**As of 2017.1 version it's on new `Punctuation` tab and options are named a bit differently:**

[image]

Comment: If you started off on an older version of Intellij (< 2017.1), you may need to toggle the settings for it to actually apply.  This was set to single quotes, but I was still seeing double quotes.  It worked after changing to double quotes, applying, changing to single quotes, and finally applying again.

Comment: "Other" tab is now "Punctuation" - as of at least Webstorm 2017.3.2

Comment: @ggranum Yes, the screenshot and the note ("On 2017.1...")  shows just that. I guess I better make it bold/more visible.

Comment: If you happen to use Vue.js with typescript, you may need to apply this setting for javascript as well. It seems that WebStorm does not apply typescript settings to Vue-files, even if they are set as `lang=ts`.

Answer (score 124):

Also if you would like to add automatic space between curly braces when adding imports like so

`import { MyComponent } from './my.component';`

you may check in tab `Spaces | Whithin | ES6 import/export braces`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for that and it was extremely bothering me.

Comment: Same as Ivan, I had no idea how to customise this and Interpolation expressions as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

In `2017-2019` this is how we do it:

1. Go to settings
2. Type `Code style` in search
3. Select `Typescript`
4. Go to `Punctuation` section
5. Select `single` quotes

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1st Things need to check in your Tslint file

```
 "quotemark": [
  true,
  "Double"
],
```

It's should be Double rather than Single because it's Failed TSLint Passed on Project Build.

Now go to your Setting | Editor | TypeScript | Punctuation

Select Single from the dropdown and Apply/Ok it.

Now Congrats your IntellijIDEA are applied Double Quotes on AutoImport.[image: For reference]

Answer (score 2):

For Intellij 2016.3 version it's on Other Tab > Generated Code > Quote Marks[image]