# Fix TsLint error/warning with a shortcut (keybinding)

Tags: angularjs, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, lint, tslint

I am currently using **TSLint** on WebStorm.

I have been trying and searching to find a way to apply a shortcut (key-binding) to make the Linting error to be fixed
 *(e.g. imports with **"** instead of **'** are considered lint errors).*

Any idea how to bind to a shortcut.

Comment: How do you do it now (some screenshots are welcome)?

Comment: Fixing it manually or consulting the suggestion from the help light bulb.

Comment: Individual Intentions/"Quick Fixes" cannot have dedicated shortcuts (there are no such functionality present in IDE ATM). What I meant was - do you use mouse to interact with that light bulb .. or keyboard? If mouse -- try `Alt+Enter` to bring that "quick fix" menu -- much faster.

Comment: I know that. But when , for example , calling a method from another component, the imports are automatically inserted. The issue is that the imports have double quotes , but on the lint config file I use single quotes .

Comment: *"The issue is that the imports have double quotes"* .. so why don't you configure Code Style so it uses right quotes in first place? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779498/783119