# How can I make WebStorm use double-quotes when generating code?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, lint

WebStorm is very helpful in that it automatically generates import statements like the following:

```
import { CART_DECREASE_STEP } from "@/store/mutation-types";
```

However it generates it using single-quotes.

How can I make it use double-quotes to match my lint-settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebStorm/PhpStorm double quotes in TypeScript auto import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779272/webstorm-phpstorm-double-quotes-in-typescript-auto-import)

Comment: Yes, indeed. That did the trick. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found here

[WebStorm/PhpStorm double quotes in TypeScript auto import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779272/webstorm-phpstorm-double-quotes-in-typescript-auto-import)

as suggested by @anstarovoyt

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a tslint or jslint, so that webstorm can configure himself to respect your rules.