# How to configure IntelliJ / WebStorm to use single quotes in code completion within *.TS, *.JS files

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, tslint

I work a lot with TypeScript files and JavaScript files using modules.

My TS/ESLint rules enforce the use of single quotes, but WebStorm always completes the code with double quotes. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebStorm/PhpStorm double quotes in TypeScript auto import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779272/webstorm-phpstorm-double-quotes-in-typescript-auto-import)

Answer (score 15):

Make sure to set up the desired code style in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript** (and **JavaScript**) - namely, set *Use single quotes always* in **Punctuation** tab.
Note that IDEA and WebStorm can import code style prerefences from `tslint.json` : open it in editor and click **Yes** when prompted to apply settings. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2455/, *Import code style from tslint.json*

Same is true for `.eslintrc` - see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/06/webstorm-2017-2-eap-172-3198/