# PhpStorm: apply double quotes when copy pasting

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I copy-paste OpenAPI docs in PhpStorm

```php
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="limit",
 *         in="query",
 *         required=true,
 *         description="Limit results"
 *      ),
```

it inserts them with single quotes, even though the copied block uses double-quotes. Any ideas on how to fix this? (P.S. I'm using the latest IDE version)

Comment: Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779272/webstorm-phpstorm-double-quotes-in-typescript-auto-import)

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj it's php, not ts

Comment: You can select an language and change the code styles in any Jetbrains IDEs

Comment: are you guessing? because your guess is wrong

Comment: This is how I changed,  go to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Editor" -> "Code Style" -> "PHP" -> "Wrapping and Braces" tab. In the "Other" section, ensure that "String literals" is set to use double quotes.

Comment: what version of phpstorm do you have? there is no such option in 2023.1.2

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj Please post a screenshot. Because I also see no "Other" section in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces" in the latest 2023.1.2 version. Perhaps it was added in the next 2023.2 version (EAP builds are already available to test)

Comment: @Majesty Please try using Paste as Plain Text (`Ctrl+Alt+Shift+V` here on Windows keymap)

Comment: @LazyOne yes indeed, it works like you suggested, but still there must be an option for this somewhere in the config. thanks!

Comment: @Majesty Try 2023.2 EAP build -- maybe it's there just as Ahmed said (no idea myself though) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/ (you can run them in parallel as each major version uses separate IDE-wide config path; just do not open the same project in both versions at the same time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by disabling "Replace unnecessary double quotes on paste", located in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> PHP.

Previously all my copied stuffs (such as HTML as well) converts into single quotes on paste. Disabling the above will retain the double quotes.

Currently using PHPStorm 2023.2.3